# defining 'reference' to an object

Tags: c#

When an object is created, a reference is returned, and not the object.

What does this mean?

```
object a = new object();
```

Here `a` holds the reference.

It would be helpful if someone explains the creation of the object, creation of references.

Comment: Eric Lippert just posted a blog about this very question.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/07/references-and-pointers-part-one.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I think of a reference as being like a set of directions to get to a house, where the house represents the object itself.

So if you were to tell someone how to get to your house, you might write down those directions on a piece of paper and give it to them - that's like assigning a reference to a variable.

Coming to your example:

```
object a = new object();
```

That's like building a new house (calling the constructor) and then on a piece of paper (the variable `a`) you write the directions to get to the new house. The paper doesn't have the house itself on it - just directions. If someone copies the contents of the piece of paper, like this:

```
object b = a;
```

that doesn't create a second house. It just copies the directions from the piece of paper `a` to the piece of paper `b`. Likewise then the two pieces of paper are independent - you could change the value of `a` to a different set of directions, and it wouldn't change what's on `b`.

I have an [article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/references.html) on this which attempts to explain it another way, which you may find helpful.

Comment: in C++ references are internally pointers, the pointers holds the address not the data, so in C# is it similar way

Comment: @Raghav: It's undefined exactly what form the "directions" take. Any way that gets you to the object. A pointer is one obvious implementation though.

Answer (score 3):

The following statement:

```
object a = new object();
```

Actually does two different things.

**First**, `new object()` allocates the necessary memory to store the instance is allocated on the heap and returns the address on the heap that just got allocated.

**Secondly**, the assignment is evaluated and assigns the value returned from `new` to `a`.

When you say "a holds a reference" it means that a is the memory on the stack (or in registers, or on the heap depending no the lifetime of the reference) that points to the heap location of the instance you just created.

Comment: While it's true for "standard" implementation of .NET, you shouldn't use the words "stack" and "heap". http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx

Comment: did u answer changed? earlier u used stack and heap

Comment: @Raghav - I updated it to be correct based on Eric Lippert's blog post that xanatos linked to. While references are typically stored on the stack, they don't need to be. They can be stored in any of the mechanisms listed based on the object's lifetime. The basic concept is the same (and, as the article mentions, it's really irrelevant where the reference is stored because the developer doesn't need to worry about that).

Comment: The reference is not a pointer (which to me is what you describe) so while the concept you describe is informative and would in most cases give the needed information it's not technically correct (Eric has a recent post on that as well)

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate a class with the `new` keyword you create an object on the heap. It is not referenced by anyone yet. If an object has no references to itself it can be soon garbage collected. To operate with an object you need to reference it. So you create a variable which contains the address of the object(the reference).

Answer (score 0):

With most modern languages you don't have to worry about references vs the object themselves.  Back in the day (eg c++) you would have to worry about reference (sometimes called pointers) and even the memory allocated for them.  Now the system (and what is called the garbage collector) worries about it for you.

Here is the details.  Your example line means the following:

```
1) allocate memory for object

2) run the constructor

3) put the memory location of that object in the variable "a"
```

What does the mean to you conceptually as a programmer?  Not much, most of the time.  In C# you can still think of the variable a as the object.  You don't have to worry about it pointing to the object under the hood.  Most of the time it does not matter.

Where it matters is when you need to be concerned about the lifetime of the object.  Because you have a reference to the object it will not be deallocated which means if it is using a system resource it will continue to do so.

When an object is no longer being referenced it will be deallocated by the garbage collector.

Comment: A reference and pointer in c++ are two different things e.g. a reference can't be null

Answer (score 0):

Another tongue-in-cheek analogy for the pile: the object is a helium balloon, and a reference is a string tied to that balloon which you are holding. Saying `new object()` is equivalent to asking a balloon guy (the memory manager) at the fair (your program) for a new balloon. He may either give you a balloon by means of handing you the string, or he may also tell you that there are no balloons left. You may find the latter very upsetting and run crying from the fair.

You may wish to share the balloon with your sibling, and here the analogy starts to fall apart. This could be seen as both you and your sibling holding onto the same string with your hands, or a second string being tied to the balloon for your sibling. Care must be taken to ensure that those who hold the string(s) tied to the balloon coordinate their movements, otherwise the balloon may be ripped or ruined.

Finally, in a language like C# when you become bored of the balloon, you can simply let go of the string. If others are still holding the string it will not go anywhere, but if they are not it floats harmlessly into a net in the sky, from where the balloon guy periodically collects the released balloons to replenish his stock. In other older languages like C, there is no such net and the balloon guy will never be able to recover the helium in that balloon to make another balloon for someone else. He would really appreciate it if you took the balloon back. This causes other problems: you may return the balloon, but forget that your sibling still wanted it. With their back turned, they don't notice you pulling the string out of their hand and later when they turn and look for it, they will find it is gone and be very upset.

Ridiculous analogy? Yes. Will it stick in your mind? Most likely :)